# How exactly does the NSIndexPath row property work

Tags: nsindexpath

I'm reading through the Big Nerd Ranch iOS guide and I have a question about this piece of code here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    }

    BNRItem *p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];
    return cell;
}
```

BNRItemStore is just a data store object and I've already added five BNRItem objects to it in the initializer method. Their string descriptions are then printed to the UI. My confusion specifically is about this line here:

```
BNRItem *p = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

The way I understand this line is that objectAtIndex: just retrieves the items in the BNRItemStore and assigns them to the variable. The question I have is this:

How is objectAtIndex: able to return all five objects to the variable *p with the argument [indexPath row]? I was under the impression that an indexPath object holds a single section and a single row. So the row property would just return a single row index. Here it looks like the array is being looped through and its 5 contents returned to the variable, which are then printed to the UI. Or is that not what's going on? What is the row property actually doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.  NSIndexPath encapsulates a section and a row.  I think your confusion is that `BNRItem *p` is not pointing to all 5 items (it's only pointing to one at a time)... rather, the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called for each row that is being displayed in the Table View.

There is another method, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` which is called.  I assume this method is returning the number 5, so `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called 5 times... each time the indexPath will have a different row, and thus print a different object.

Comment: That clears it up...wish the Apple documentation explained it that way because with a lot of these datasource methods, it's not exactly clear what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @MikaSchiller - this documentation might help you:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: Quick question: Let's say I still have 5 items in the data store and I want to put 2 items in section 0 and 3 items in section 1. So first I would do this: 

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

 if (section == 0) {
  return 2
 }

 if (section == 1) {
  return 3
 }
}

Comment: That's correct (although, and I'm sure you know this, the code wouldn't compile as you've written because you don't have a return statement outside of an if block. Make sure you've overridden `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` to return 2.

Comment: And to add each section's rows to the tableview, would this be the correct way:

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    ....
    
    if ([indexPath section] == 0) {

     BNRItem *p1 = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
     [[cell textLabel] setText:[p1 description]];


    if ([indexPath section] == 1) {

     BNRItem *p2 = [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
     [[cell textLabel] setText:[p2 description]];

    return cell;
}

Comment: No, that won't work, because you are going to the same data store. The first section would be correct, but the second section would repeat the first row.  The NSIndexPath {section, row} would be {0,0} and {0,1} for the first section, and {1,0} for the second. Since it's going to the same data store, you would need to add an index on the second section like: `[[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row + 2]`